# Add "card" inside a list

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, include, scrollview

i've a question...i need to add,in this case include, more than one xml into a scrollview...the xml of the fragment is this

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#D9DADE"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/intestazione"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/dettaglio_richiesta"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_card_background"
    android:padding="15dp" />
    
 <include
    android:id="@+id/note"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/dettaglio_note"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_card_background"
    android:padding="15dp" 
    />   


  <include
    android:id="@+id/articoli"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/dettaglio_articoli"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_card_background"
    android:padding="15dp" />   
 
 <include
    android:id="@+id/preventivi"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/dettaglio_preventivi"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_card_background"
    android:padding="15dp" />  
    
 <include
    android:id="@+id/tragitto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/dettaglio_tragitto"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_card_background"
    android:padding="15dp" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/TestCard"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      android:background="@drawable/selector_card_background"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:padding="15dp"
      android:text="FINE DELLE CARD" />

</LinearLayout>

    

</ScrollView>
```

If,for example,i have more item of Preventivi,that is an xml imported and populated once that this is loaded,how can i do?
How is possible to insert more of this...

`

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/preventivi"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/dettaglio_preventivi"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_card_background"
        android:padding="15dp" />
```

`

so i can see multiple cards in the parent xml?
Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: This is not the right way of going about it. Make a custom ListView, add these to it and then populate them via an adapter.

Comment: So if I wanto to add different type of cards in the same list i have to use different adapters?

Comment: I've done the custom adapter,so now i can have a listview with multiple cards...but if i try to use this listview inside an xml...i can see only one item of the list.How can i see the others elements? :)

Comment: Ok the problem is that i have a ListView inside a ScollView...to solve i need to force the height of the ListView based on child...maybe

Comment: Ok solved...i used a method to force the height to the listview :)
i used 2 asynctask for populate the 2 listview and works perfectly...of course also 2 adapter...one for each item :)
I don't know how poste here the intere solution...